# Entity (External Content Type) cannot be found with Namespace = 'http://server1', Name = 'user_information'

Tags: 2013, site-collection, publishing-site, external-content-type

I restored site collection backup from one farm to another. I am displaying data from this content type on one of my publishing site page. I had already created this external content type before restoring backup. Now after restoring when I try to access that page on new server then I get the following error:

```
Entity (External Content Type) cannot be found with Namespace = 'http://server1', Name = 'user_information'
```

I am basically moving from `http://server1` to `http://server2`. I can see the content type is created on server2 and its name space is "server2" but looks like it is still trying to find "server1" hence the error. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by importing and then exporting external content type from server1 to server2.